# Binding "foreach" inside a widget with asynchronous call for data

Tags: asynchronous, knockout.js, typescript, widget, durandal

I am beginner with Durandal, Knockout and TypeScript

I have a problem with templating with “foreach” binding in widget. 
Would appreciate any help

I need to create a pagination for products as widget. For this purpose I’ve created an observable array totalPagesHolder and pushed values in it as a number of my pages (f.ex. if we have 3 pages, this array will contain [1,2,3])

I work with promises and take the length of array of all my products asynchronously.

**widgets/pagination/viewmodel.ts**

```
class viewmodel {
    ...
    public totalPagesHolder: KnockoutObservableArray<number> =     ko.observableArray<number>([]);
    ...
    activate(){
         this.totalFetch().done( (total) => {
            let pages = Math.floor(this.total() / this.pageSize);
            pages += this.total() % this.pageSize > 0 ? 1 : 0;
            for (let i = 1; i < pages +1 ; i++) {
                this.totalPagesHolder.push(i);
            }

            console.log("totalPagesHolder", this.totalPagesHolder());

    });
}
```

**wigdets/pagination/view.html**

```
<ul class="pager"> 
          <li><button>Next</button></li>
          <!-- ko with: totalPagesHolder -->
          <li><button data-bind="text: $index() + 1, click: gotoPage">...   </button></li>
         <!-- /ko -->
         <li><button class="btn btn-default">  Previous  </button></li>
    </ul>
```

**my-view.html**

```
 <div class=”page”>
        <div data-bind="widget: {kind:'pagination'}"></div>
    </div>
```

If I don’t use a widget, then knockout renders all the buttons

**my-viewmodel.ts**

```
class MyModel {
    public totalPagesHolder = ko.observable([1,2,3,4]);
}
export = MyModel;
```

**my-view.html**

```
<ul class="pager"> 
      <li><button>Next</button></li>
      <!-- ko with: totalPagesHolder -->
      <li><button data-bind="text: $index() + 1, click: $parent.gotoPage">...   </button></li>
     <!-- /ko -->
     <li><button class="btn btn-default">  Previous  </button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Seems like a widget would get its own scope. You could try `with: $parent.totalPagesHolder` or passing `totalPagesHolder to the widget explicitly, assuming widgets take parameters (I don't know Durandal).

Comment: Shouldn't your `with` binding be a `foreach`? Also, where is `gotoPage` defined? Shouldn't it be prefixed by `$parent` or `$root`?  Lastly: `MyModel.totalPagesHolder` isn't an `observableArray`, is that correct?

Comment: Thans for answers. 
I've tried all combination - foreach/with, $parent.totalPagesHolder. Unfortunately I have the same result.
My gotoPage() is defined in widgets/pagination/viewmodel.ts out of activate() and I call it inside activate().
and no, MyModel.totalPagesHolder is observable array

Comment: I have a Chrome plugin Knockoutjs context debugger for detecting Knockout context.. So I can see what $data, $parent, $root etc contain. Look at screenshot there http://prntscr.com/cq7aha. So totalPagesHolder is outside of $parent or $root.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may need to set up your widget so it takes a variable when it is activated to determine the number of buttons to show.

Are you seeing in your page source evidence that the widget is being rendered, even with no page buttons, or not at all?